# A cup of milk dregs has turned a deep blue color. What is growing in it?

Tags: species-identification, food

Ok, so yes this is gross and all. But it was too amazing to me to keep to myself. I left a cup with a small amount of leftover milk from "honey bunches of oats" out for like 2-3 days and this is what I found:

[image: blue milk]

It's a shiny (might I say pretty?) paint-like shade of turquoise. Can anyone identify what is growing is cup or shed light on what happened? I've never seen milk go off like this before.